# .Bat File - deleting 4 days old backup if atleast 3 days old file already exist

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, backup

This is my first post & take in mind my native language isn't English.

`.bat` file so far:

```
C:

Cd\

forfiles /p Z:\SQL /s /m *.bak /d -4 /c "cmd /c del /q @path"

forfiles /p Z:\SQL /s /m *.trn /d -4 /c "cmd /c del /q @path"
```

What I want with this file:

I want it to delete 4 days old backup & log files. This `.Bat` file works with that - the risk comes now - if the backup/log program for some reason stop and the person in charge is sick for 4 days - the `.bat` file will delete the only valid backup I have.

So what I ask for:

Is there someone out there that knows a way to switch in the `.bat` file so that it looks for at least 3 days worth of files - NOTE Not just 3 files, but it has to be from 3 previous days in a row.

Example: The system takes backup Monday (1), system crashes Thursday (2). When the scheduler runs the backup at Tuesday (4) it will just delete the Monday backup (which is my only valid one) because its 4 days old.

That's where it comes in that I want it to check: Do I have any other `.bak`/`.trn` files the last 3 days Yes/No?

No = Don't delete.

Yes = Delete everything over 4 days old.

Hope I have explained myself somewhat understandably.

Thanks for reading, hope you can help me out!

Comment: I think you could reduce this question to max of 10 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can count them ahead of time to make the decisions.  Here's one way to do it.  Unfortunately FORFILES doesn't allow you to easily find files newer than 4 days ago, so we find the older ones and subtract from the total.

Loop through the files and add the ones that match your deletion criteria to a text file:

```
forfiles /p Z:\SQL /s /m *.bak /d -4 /c "CMD /c ECHO @fname" > BAKfiles.tmp
forfiles /p Z:\SQL /s /m *.trn /d -4 /c "CMD /c ECHO @fname" > TRNfiles.tmp
```

Next, use the `FIND /c` command to count the lines that have quotation marks in them, and use `FOR /F` to parse the total from the output after the colon.  You need to do this for each file type, but I'm only showing one for the general form.

```
FOR /F %%C IN ('dir *.BAK^| find "File(s)"') do SET BAKTOTAL=%%C
FOR /F %%C IN ('dir *.TRN^| find "File(s)"') do SET TRNTOTAL=%%C
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=:" %%C IN ('cmd /c find /c """"  BAKfiles.tmp') DO SET BAKDEL=%%C
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims=:" %%C IN ('cmd /c find /c """"  TRNfiles.tmp') DO SET TRNDEL=%%C
SET /A BAKCOUNT=%BAKTOTAL% - %BAKDEL%
SET /A TRNCOUNT=%TRNTOTAL% - %TRNDEL%
```

Then evaluate the count with `IF` to see if you have enough files to meet your threshold, and run your deletion commands.

```
IF %BAKCOUNT% GEQ 3 IF %TRNCOUNT% GEQ 3 GOTO DELETEFILES
ECHO Not enough files were found.  Skipping deletion.
GOTO ENDING
:DELETEFILES
forfiles /p Z:\SQL /s /m *.bak /d -4 /c "cmd /c del /q @path"
forfiles /p Z:\SQL /s /m *.trn /d -4 /c "cmd /c del /q @path"
:ENDING
del /q BAKfiles.tmp
del /q TRNfiles.tmp
```